# Extending an abstract class in the WAR from a class in the lib folder

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, servlets, classloader

I want to enable the following scenario:

- my web application (WAR file) is deployed on Tomcat on its own
- my web application provides an API for extensions in the form of an `IFace` interface and `AbstractIFace` abstract base implementation, whose class files are deployed within the WAR file
- extensions to the applications are delivered as JAR files to be placed somewhere in the classpath (i.e. external to the WAR)

I compiled a `ConcreteIFace` class which extends `AbstractIFace` and packaged it into a JAR. I put the JAR in `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib` and deployed the WAR in `webapps`. When I try the following from a servlet in the WAR:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("ConcreteIFace");
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: AbstractIFace
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1698)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    com.backbase.sample.DummyServlet.service(DummyServlet.java:14)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

A similar stack trace is presented if `ConcreteIFace` directly implements `IFace` instead of going through `AbstractIFace`

My questions are:

- as all the required classes are in the application classpath, why do I have `NoClassDefFound`?
- is it even possible to achieve the scenario I presented at the beginning? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In web applications, the classpath is segregated. The web applications cannot see each-other's classes, Tomcat cannot see the apps' classes, the apps cannot see Tomcat's internal classes (only the exposed interfaces like the Servlet API).

Web applications are supposed to be self-contained, and container-independent.

The easiest way would be to re-package the war file to also include the plugins.

Other options include going up to enterprise archives, which can have interdependencies, or embedding the web server in the application (as opposed to the other way around).

Comment: I understand the point, thanks. But apparently the app *can* access the container classes, and the problem is on the other way around: looking at the error it's about `AbstractIFace`, meaning `ConcreteIFace` was indeed found and was getting loaded. Right?

Comment: Yes, the app can see (some) container classes, but not the other way around. ConcreteIFace is part of the container (now that you moved it to lib), so it cannot see its parent class (which is part of the app). When you compiled it, you had to give it access to the classes in the app as well, right? If you want to go with TOMCAT_HOME/lib, you have to break out all that stuff into a jar file, like @Slavus suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Your API classes are located in WAR and are not accessible to the classes in  $TOMCAT_HOME/lib.
One suggestion would be to separate your API-a IFace and AbstractIFaceClass to separate jar and place it $TOMCAT_HOME/lib.

Comment: Doable, if you can separate those pieces out cleanly. Won't work well, though, if that AbstractIFaceClass depends on a lot of other things in your web app (you'd have to move all of those transitive dependencies as well).

Comment: If you can't separate this things you have bad design.